# Issue with encoding apostope in javascript in rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an application that gets response form json and the response has text `father's`. when I try to alert the response i get `father&#39;s`, but when i print the variable from same js as `alert("<%= p @response["result"][0]["title"]%>")` I get `father's` in the rails console.

Please help me figure out the issue

Answer (score 0):

`&#39 ;` is actually is the apostrophe in unicode. It should be fine on how you store it. The alert may just spawn up the unicode and not render it as normal text